# module.exports with object

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, routes, export

I'm starting with node.js and javascript server side. I think, maybe I got confused with the module.exports thing. And I'm pretty sure it's a noob issue.

I'm trying to do a simple task :

oAuth - controler [oAuth.js]

```
  module.exports = function() {
  return {
    tryLogin :function(Username,Password){

   }
  };
}
```

oAuth - dispatcher [route.js]

```
module.exports = function(app){


    app.post('/api/oAuth/login', function(req, res){
        console.log("Trying to log with :");
        console.log(req.body.Username);
        console.log(req.body.Password);


        var oAuthCtrl = require('./oAuth.js');
        var result = oAuthCtrl.tryLogin(req.body.Username,req.body.Password);
        res.send(result);

    });
}
```

And the console result is :

```
TypeError: Object function (width) {
  return {
    tryLogin :function(Username,Password){

   }
  };
} has no method 'tryLogin'
```

What I want is an oAuth object inside my oAuthCtrl variable. This way I'll be able to call my tryLogin method.

The end point here is to build an oAuth module using passeport.js with some block and page views and methods like register, tryLogin, logout etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `tryLogin` in an anonymous function when you export it.

Simply put, `module.exports` *is* an object. You could almost think of it as a sort of "return value" from calling `require` on a script.

You just want

```
// oauth.js
function tryLogin {
  // ...
}

module.exports.tryLogin = tryLogin;
```

---

Here's an alternative based on your comment

```
// oauth.js
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.tryLogin = function tryLogin() {
  // ...
};

module.exports = MyClass;
```

In the last line, we're effectively *replacing* the default empty object provided by `module.exports` with our "class".

Comment: First thing first : thank you. With this how can I add class members ? I don't want to export a function but an object

Comment: Console said : Authentification succeed. Nice explaination on the module.exports. I feel way better now.